# JavaScript Scrolling scrolls down where the element cannot be seen on the screen

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning selenium with Java and I'm trying to use javascript to scroll down to a particular element.

The script that I have written scrolls down, but goes way below where the element cannot be seen. Not sure why this has been happening.

The error I get in console is the following
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ScriptTimeoutException: script timeout`

Can anyone help me understand what exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
public class JavaScriptScrolling {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        driver.get("https://www.asda.com/");
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")).click();
        
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        
        JavaScriptUtils jUtil = new JavaScriptUtils(driver);
        
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Explore more']"));
        
        jUtil.scrollIntoView(element);
        
        element.click();
    }

}
```

The method to from the JavaScriptUtils class for scrolling is the one below

```
public void scrollIntoView(WebElement element) {
        js.executeAsyncScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due to `scrollIntoView`. To solve this issue, you can adjust the scrollIntoView method to make the element align with the top or bottom of the container as needed. Here's how you can do it:

```
public void scrollElementIntoView(WebElement element, boolean alignToTop) {
    String script = "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(" + alignToTop + ");";
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, element);
}
```

Then, you can call this method with `alignToTop` set to true or false based on your use case. To align the element to top, use true; if you want to align it to bottom, use false.

```
// scroll the element to the top of the view
jUtil.scrollElementIntoView(element, true);

// scroll the element to the bottom of the view
jUtil.scrollElementIntoView(element, false);
```

Comment: Its aligning correctly when I pass false (To the bottom of the container) & the script works fine but with the boolean set to true, the alignment is incorrect and it scrolls way below the element until its not visible for the click.